# Multilingual winforms application

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, multilingual

I want my C# (winforms) application to be multilingual. My idea is:

- I will have my translations in some text file(s), each "sentence" or phrase will have it's unique ID (integer)
- at the start-up of the app I will iterate through all controls on all forms I have in my app (I suppose this should be done in each form's *'Load'* event handler) and I will test the control of it's type
- i.e. if it is a button or menu item, I will read it's default *'Text'* property, locate this phrase in one text file, read it's unique ID and through this ID will locate translated phrase in (other) text file
- then I will overwrite that *'Text'* property of the control with translated phrase

This enables me to have separate text file with phrases for each and every language (easy to maintain individual translation in the future - only 1 txt file)

1. I would like to hear from you - proffesionals if there is some better / easier / faster / more 'pro' way how to accomplish this.
2. What format of translation *text file* should I use (plain text, XML, ini....) - it should be human readable. I don't know if finding a phrase in XML would be in C# faster than going line-by-line in plain text file and searching for given phrase/string...?
3. **EDIT** - I want users (community) to be able to translate my app for them into their native language without my interaction (it means Microsoft's resources are out of the game)

Thank you very much in advance.

**CLOSED - My solution:**
Looks like I'm staying at my original concept - every phrase will be in separate line of plain text file - Unicode encoding (and ID at the beginning of the line). I was thinking about deleting ID's too and to use only the line numbers, but it would need advanced text editor (Notepad shows no line numbers) and if somebody accidentaly hits shortcut for "Delete line" and doesn't notice that, whole app would go crazy :)

`//sample of my translation text file for one language

0001:Text of my first button

0002:Text of my first label

0003:MessageBox title text

...etc etc`

Comment: Be aware that you may need to adjust the positions of labels and buttons too depending on the language as some translations can be extremely  long when compared to the original text. (Something the standard method of translations already caters for)

Comment: Yes I know. But for my purpose it's OK to open the application from time to time, switch to every language and check the appearance. I have only couple of forms. If something is too long, I will edit the visual and recompile. This would be less work for me, than recompile every time somebody sends me new phrases. But thanks anyway - very good point !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the users to edit the translations through your application while keeping things simple and quick, resource file is best. If you don't like it, the second best option is XML file.

Still, to answer you question on how to do it best with a *text file*, it is pretty straight forward: You just make sure that your unique identifier (`int` probably) are in order (validate before using the file). Then to search quickly, you use the technique of the halves.

You look for number X, so you go to the file's middle line. If id > x, to go to ¼ of the file, etc.

You cut in two until you get to the right line. This is the fastest know research method.

**NOTE:** Beware of the things that are external to the application but need translation: External file items, information contained in a database, etc.

Comment: Well, I don't think resources are simple and quick solution for somebody who has no programming knowledge (it means no VisualStudio, no advanced text editor). Or is there some simple way how people can edit resources which I am missing? Thanks for answer and 'the halves' anyway...

Comment: I tried to find a simple way how to read the file and jump from line X to line Y, but it looks like C# doesn't have any lib supporting this? Looks like I will read whole file (10-20 kB) into a List<string> obj and then process it.... Or??

Answer (score 3):

[Why not use Microsoft's resource file method?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) You won't need to write any complex custom code this way.

Comment: Well.... that is not what I wanted... I want users of my app to translate it for them, because I can't speak all languages - it's better if people do it in their native language. And they have no clue about programming and coding. I also have no time left to add new translated phrases to app and compile it every time some user send me translation update. I'm willing to write some simple code which will check install directory (on app startup) and if it finds translation file (files will be named with some mask) then my app will automatically include this language in the options list.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are somewhat invested in the "one text file" idea, or else you would probably lean towards the standard way and use Microsoft's resource files. Handling for resource files is built-in, and the controls are already keyed to support it. But, as you are probably aware, each translation goes into it's own resource file. So you are left juggling multiple files to distribute with your app.

With a custom, roll-your-own solution, you can probably trim it down to one unicode file. But you will have to loop through the controls to set the text, and then look up the text for each one. As you add control types, you will have to add support in your code for them. Also, your text file will grow in large chunks as you add languages, so you will have to account for that as well.

I still lean towards using the resource files, but your phrasing suggests you already don't like that solution, so I don't think I have changed your mind.

**Edit:**

Since you want the solution separated from the app to avoid having to recompile, you could distribute SQL-CE database files for each language type. You can store the text values in NVARCHAR fields.

That will make your querying easier, but raises the self-editing requirements. You would have to provide a mechanism for users to add their own translation files, as well as edit screens.

**Edit 2:**

Driving towards a solution. :)

You can use a simple delimited text file, encoded in Unicode, with a convention based naming system. For example:

**en-US.txt**

```
FormName,ControlName,Text
"frmMain","btnSubmit","Save"
"frmMain","lblDescription","Description"
```

Then you can use the CurrentUICulture to determine which text file to load for localization, falling back to en-US if no file is found. This lets the users create (and also change!) their own localization files using common text editors and without any steep learning curve.

Comment: I want it to be one separate file for each language, I also use just couple of standard controls in my app, but regarding MS resources - check my comment above please (under Justin's answer)

Comment: Hmmm... so it means to write another application - for my users to edit translation texts.
I think I'm sticking at my original text files (at least for now) which are easy to edit and for me it's less coding than to code whole another app.
The question now is - what kind of text files to use. For which there is better support from C# (libraries) so I have easier and faster coding. I don't know if finding a phrase in XML would be in C# faster than going line-by-line in plain text file and searching for given phrase/string...?

Comment: I would not do XML, as that will cause a steep learning curve for users to self-edit. Maybe just a simple comma-delimited unicode file?

Comment: Thanks for your effort! Looks like I'm staying at my original concept - every phrase in separate line (ID at the beginning of the line). But no form or control names - it's additional work for me to write to the text file and additional risk that some user-looser will accidentaly hit the key somewhere in the name of the control and the control won't translate. I was thinking about deleting ID's too and to use only line numbers, but it needs advanced text editor (Notepad shows no line numbers) and if somebody accidentaly hits shortcut for "Delete line", whole app would go crazy :)

Comment: Thanks once again. I marked as "Accepted" Mathieu's answer because the idea of "halves", but I'm giving you upvotes for your support. Thanks!